# cmake add_subdirectory error only with cmake command line but not cmake-gui on windows (with source checked out at root of a drive letter)

Tags: windows, cmd, cmake, cmake-gui

I'm working on 3dtk which uses CMake to build. You can find its CMakeLists.txt here: https://sourceforge.net/p/slam6d/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/CMakeLists.txt

In several places it uses the `add_subdirectory` directive and never supplies a second argument (the `binary_dir`).

This seems to be no problem when calling `ccmake` out-of-tree on linux or when using `cmake-gui` on windows as in both cases, the project configures successfully.

But when I run plain `cmake` on windows in the command prompt, then I get several errors like this:

```
CMake Error at Z:/CMakeLists.txt:471 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory not given a binary directory but the given source
  directory "Z:/src/slam6d" is not a subdirectory of "Z:/". When specifying
  an out-of-tree source a binary directory must be explicitly specified.
```

I suspect that I'm just missing an option to the `cmake` command but which one?

Just as with `cmake-gui` on Windows where I specify a different path for `Where to build the binaries` than for `where is the source code` to make an out-of-tree build and just as with `ccmake` on Linux where I run `ccmake` in a subdirectory of my source like this `ccmake ..`, I'm running `cmake` on Windows from within a subdirectory of my source.

So what are `cmake-gui` and `ccmake` doing that `cmake` does not and where manual intervention is required?

Edit: after finding the solution it turns out that the problem was that my source directory was directly a windows drive letter instead of a subdirectory of one.

Comment: What is the exact command line (`cmake ...`) which results in that error message?

Comment: @tamas.kenez: it turns out that the problem was, that my cmake source was at the top of a drive letter instead of a subdirectory. This information was missing in my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this is a bug in cmake. [Quoting](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2015-August/061332.html) David Cole:

> Put your source in a sub-directory. CMake simply does not work at the
>   root of a drive letter on Windows. CMakeLists.txt MUST be in at least
>   one sub-directory underneath a root drive letter path.

There are also some open bugreports about this issue:

- http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15134
- http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=10072

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the bug reports josch has given, it does not look like CMake will be fixed with this in some near future. I encountered this problem while using cmake on android NDK project.

My solution was to use junction (I use windows 10), I could not move source folders to sub directories.

To make junction use mklink command (in cmd.exe):

```
cd z:\
mklink /J MyProjectJp z:\
```

in explorator you will see a folder `z:\MyProjectJp`with exact same view as `z:\`. Now to build your project enter `z:\MyProjectJp`.